# Where to get Python ANTLR package to use StringTemplate?

Tags: python, antlr, stringtemplate

I'd like to do some code generation, and StringTemplate looks like a pretty good tool for the job. I easy_installed stringtemplate3 from PyPi, but when I try to import it I get:

```
ImportError: No module named antlr
```

I am confused by this because I thought that ANTLR depended on StringTemplate (as the website says), not the other way around. In any case, I cannot find the correct package to fix  this. Installing [antlr_python_runtime](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/antlr_python_runtime/3.1.2) did not help.

Any hints?

Comment: I believe Antlr and ST have cyclic dependencies, but with one depending on an earlier version of the other.  i.e. if ST 4 depends on Antlr 3, Antlr 3 depends on ST 3 rather than 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the `python-antlr` package installed to use `stringtemplate3`. Example of installing on Ubuntu:

```
% sudo aptitude install python-antlr
% virtualenv ~/virt
% . ~/virt/bin/activate
(virt)~% easy_install stringtemplate3
(virt)~% python -c 'import stringtemplate3'
```

FWIW this package is named `py26-antlr3` on Macports (not sure which platform / package manager you're using).

Comment: hmm, for my purposes, I need the solution to be cross platform and simple to install. I guess stringtemplate is not the solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  stringtemplate3 does not use antlr3, it uses antlr2.7~ .  I had to manually install it by downloading http://www.antlr2.org/download/antlr-2.7.7.tar.gz , unzipping it, navigating to antlr-2.7.7/lib/python , and running python setup.py install .  After this, the dependency was met.

Comment: The tip from @I82Much worked for me. I'm actually trying to get antlr3 to run. I got antlr-3.1.3.jar, created a virtualenv, installed antlr_python_runtime-3.1.3.tar.gz per `python setup.py install`, then `pip install stringtemplate3`, and finally installed antlr2.7 as explained above. Crazy that chain of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and packaged the *antlr* python library: you can `pip install git+git://github.com/kynan/antlr.git#egg=antlr` to install it.