# How to generate a list from a * rule in ANTLR3?

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr3

I have the following grammar:

```
grammar Test;

options {
  lang = Python;
}

declaration returns [value]
    :     'enum' ID { statement* }
                 { $value = {'id': $ID.text,
                             'fields': $statement.value}
                 }
    ;

statement returns [value]
    :     ID ':' INT ';' { $value = {'id': $ID.text, 'value': int($INT.text)} }
    ;
```

To parse syntax of type:

```
enum Test {
  Foo: 3;
  Bar: 5;
}
```

However, I am struggling with getting the statement* rule into a list of statements. I want my final parsed object to look like:

```
declaration = {
  'id': 'Test',
  'fields': [
    {'id': 'Foo', 'value': 3},
    {'id': 'Bar', 'value': 5},
}
```

I can parse each of the `statement` results correctly, so that each `$statement.value` is correct.
But, given the asterisk on `statement*` in rule `declaration`, is there a way I can condense it into a list of fields easily ? I was hoping to have some sort of syntax that gets me this option for free.

Right now this just takes the last statement, so it returns:

```
declaration = {
  'id': 'Test',
  'fields': [
    {'id': 'Bar', 'value': 5},
}
```

I want a generic solution because my grammar has a lot of rules of the form:

```
some_declaration
      :     keyword ID '{' declaration_statement* '}'
      ;
```

Note: I am coding this in Python.
I have tried coding this as a parser followed by a tree grammar, but even then the last element is the only one I get, the rest are discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
declaration returns [value]
    :     'enum' ID 
                 { $value = {'id': $ID.text,
                             'fields': []}
                 }
           '{' (r=statement
                 { $value['fields'].append($r.value) }
             )*
           '}'
    ;
```

Or you can also pass your fields list to the statement rule as a parameter, and append new values there. Something like this:

```
declaration returns [value]
    :     'enum' ID 
                 { $value = {'id': $ID.text,
                             'fields': []}
                 }
                 { list = $value['fields']
                 }
            '{' statement[list]* '}'
    ;

statement[list]
    :     ID ':' INT ';' { $list.append({'id': $ID.text, 'value': int($INT.text)}) }
    ;
```

Depends on what you want, but probably the first option is a bit nicer.

Here you can find some more examples on returning values from one rule to another:
[Two basic ANTLR questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565974/two-basic-antlr-questions)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the first construct that you mentioned.
Also, what's the use of the += operator then ?

Comment: do you mean usng `+=` instead of `append` (e.g. `$value['fields']+=$r.value` vs `$value['fields'].append($r.value)`)? it is slightly different, check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results)

Comment: Ah, no I meant the antlr3 += operator. I saw a few uses of it in the form: `c=ID ('.' c+=ID)+`

Comment: Ahha! `+=` is useful to have a list of matching tokens or to collect ASTs, but I don't think that you can simply use it with a grammar rule. so you cannot just say `l+=statement` (which probably you'd need here). Perhaps, you could say `(ids+=ID ':' ints+=INT)*` in the declaration, instead of `statement*`, and process the `ids` and `ints` lists. but it's not a nice solution ;) Check out section 4.3 of the _The Definitive ANTLR Reference_, or just try to replace `ID` in `statement` with `ids+=ID` and see the generated Python code what happens there.