# Install stringtemplate3 for python

Tags: python, antlr, stringtemplate

I tried to run Python/cminus example.
From `http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stringtemplate3/3.1`, I installed stringtemplate3 for python with `sudo python setup.py install`.

When I run cminus.py that starts with this code.

```
import sys
import antlr3
import stringtemplate3
```

I got errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cminus.py", line 3, in <module>
    import stringtemplate3
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stringtemplate3/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from stringtemplate3.templates import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stringtemplate3/templates.py", line 35, in <module>
    import antlr
ImportError: No module named antlr
```

It looks like that stringtemplate3 uses antlr not antlr3.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Couldn't you just modify stringtemplate3 so it uses antlr3?

Comment: I could not reproduce this. When I install stringtemplate3, and use _that_ particular build, I don't get a `ImportError: No module named antler`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an answer from this page - [Where to get Python ANTLR package to use StringTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198902/where-to-get-python-antlr-package-to-use-stringtemplate)

1. goto http://www.antlr2.org/download/antlr-2.7.7.tar.gz
2. unzip it to go to lib/python directory
3. run `sudo python setup.py install`.

I had to install antler from antlr2.7